# Assignment operator not available in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator

The assignment operator in base class does not seem to be available in derived class. Given this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
    int value;
public:
    A& operator=(int value){
        this->value = value;
        return *this;
    }
};

class B : public A{};

int main(){
    B b;
    b = 0; // Does not work
    return 0;
}
```

GCC 6.4 says:

> error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'B' and 'int')

What is happening?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Every class has at least one assignment operator implicitly defined when we don't provide one ourselves.

And when a member function in a derived class is defined with the same name as a member in the base class, it hides all the base class definitions for that name.

You can use a using declaration, but be warned that it will pull *all* the members named `operator=` and allow code like this:

```
A a;
B b;
b = a;
```

Which is slightly dubious.

Comment: I actually had to read [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54551807/4143855) to make sense of your second paragraph, but once I understood that your answer is very informative.

Answer (score 20):

In order to make it work, you need to bring the `operator=` into `B`'s scope:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
using A::operator=;
};
```

According to the standard [class.copy.assign/8]:

> Because a copy/move assignment operator is implicitly declared for a
>   class if not declared by the user, a base class copy/move assignment
>   operator is always hidden by the corresponding assignment operator of
>   a derived class (16.5.3).

So, because the `B::operator=` has been implicitly declared, it has hidden `A::operator=`, which requires you to bring it into scope if you want to use it.

Further quote from the standard [over.ass/1]

> An assignment operator shall be implemented by a non-static member
>   function with exactly one parameter. **Because a copy assignment
>   operator operator= is implicitly declared for a class if not declared
>   by the user (15.8), a base class assignment operator is always hidden
>   by the copy assignment operator of the derived class.**

Emphasis is mine.

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out by the other existing answers, the implicitly generated assignment operator of `B` hides the assignment operator defined in `A`. This is true for any non-virtual member function in a base class, the only specialty here is the automatically generated assignment operator.

But try to figure out first whether you really want to do this. Imagine your class `B` has data members that need to be initialized in some way. How does using the assignment from `A` affect these data members? `A` doesn't know anything of its derived class data members, they would be left untouched. Have a look at the following scenario where the assignment operator has been made available through a using directive:

```
class B : public A {
   public:
      using A::operator=;

      int m = 0; // Default-initialize data member to zero
};

B b;
b.m = 42;
b = 0; // Doesn't touch B::m... intended? A bug? Definitely weird.
```

So yes, it is possible, but error-prone and dangerous, especially when it comes to future modifications of the subclass.

Comment: It does not behave differently, the same issue will arise with any other method.

Comment: @spectras "same issue" ?? usually mehtods are inherited by derived classes and can be used without further measures. Any other method will not be implicitly declared by the compiler

Comment: @user463035818 the issue here is name hiding. See Some programmer dude's answer. You'll encounter this issue anytime a method in derived class has the same name as methods in base class ^^

Comment: @spectras ok, thanks, now I understand what you mean, though OP didnt declare a `operator=` in the derived and it is special with regard to hiding

Comment: @spectras Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed this part of the answer.

Comment: The best answer, imo, since it addresses *why* hiding the assignment operator is desirable, and the caveats with dragging it in.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the compiler will add an implicit assignment operator for the `B` class, declared as

```
B& operator=(const B&);
```

This operator will ***hide*** the operator from `A`, so the compiler will not know about it.

The solution is to tell the compiler to also use the operator from `A` with the `using` keyword:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::operator=;
};
```

Comment: Isn't this only true because of the implicitly declared copy assignment in `B` hiding `A::operator=`?

Comment: @spectras Yes that's true, which is why I updated the answer (just when you posted the comment).